# Batch file that hides open cmd windows

Tags: .net, cmd

I have a console application which runs another 3 console applications.

I need to write a script like a batch file or vb script which can show/hides all open cmd windows on my windows xp/7.

How can I do this?

Comment: have you tried this yourself? Perhaps try it first them come to SO with the code you have and ask a specific question on your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using a command line utility called nircmd which provides an additional library of commands. The win command allows manipulation of windows. The following command will hide any windows with cmd.exe in the title bar:

nircmd win hide stitle cmd.exe

A hidden window can also be revealed by replacing "hide" with "show".